# Alterar cor do pin default do Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Bom dia pessoal, é a minha primeira pergunta aqui, então se eu fizer algo fora do padrão já peço desculpas antecipadas.

Preciso alterar a cor padrão do pin do google maps para algum valor hexadecimal, seria possível? Já antecipo que não posso criar pngs de cada cor e buscar por uma url porque a cor vem do banco de dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo o meu código:

```js
var marcador = new MarkerWithLabel
({
  position    : {lat: parseFloat (dados.latitude), lng: parseFloat (dados.longitude)},
  raiseOnDrag : true,
  map         : mapa,
  icon        : // preciso fazer algo aqui para que o pin assuma a co com base no hexadecimal que vem da variável
  visible     : true
});
```

Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 1):

Existem alguns marcadores de cores diferentes que você pode usar; [azul](http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png), [vermelho](http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png), [roxo](http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/purple-dot.png), [amarelo](http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png), [verde](http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png).

Daí você pode usar a estrutura que colocou na pergunta e colocar um desses marcadores como `icon`:

```
var marcador = new MarkerWithLabel
({
  position    : {lat: parseFloat (dados.latitude), lng: parseFloat (dados.longitude)},
  raiseOnDrag : true,
  map         : mapa,
  icon        : 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png hexadecimal'
  visible     : true
});
```

Podes dar uma olhada [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095574/google-maps-api-3-custom-marker-color-for-default-dot-marker) do *soen* que é mais ou menos o que você pretende fazer.